# Oracle connectivity- batch file

Tags: database, oracle, batch-file, server, monitoring

I want to develop a batch file which tests the database connectivity & server availability and the result should be written on some log file or database and also that program should execute on server in specified interval of time. And also I want to create a website which will show the database uptime and downtime. How can I achieve all this? Suggest me some technology pls. And I want my output to be a website which will show the server total availability time and downtime.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a java class to check and log the connectivity in DB.

Then invoke the java class using a shell script which could be run in specified interval of time(using cron in linux).

Then write a simple web page to show the result(read from DB).

Comment: Hi alvin, thanks for ur suggestion. Can u explain how to invoke the Java class using shell script.. becoz I haven't used shell script

Comment: java HelloWorld.class